Hybris Datahub filter RawDEBMAS IDOC value
We have a requirement where we need to store E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-KUNN2 (from RawDEBMas IDOC) to Hybris custom string field (payerID) when E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARVW == RE
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DEBMAS07>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    ........
    ........
    <E1KNVVM SEGMENT="1">
        <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
            <PARVW>RG</PARVW>
            <KUNN2>0000005875</KUNN2>
            <PARZA>001</PARZA>
        </E1KNVPM>
        <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
            <PARVW>RE</PARVW>
            <KUNN2>0000001009</KUNN2>
            <PARZA>000</PARZA>
        </E1KNVPM>
        <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
            <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
            <KUNN2>0000005875</KUNN2>
            <PARZA>001</PARZA>
        </E1KNVPM>
        ......

I already tried below approach but didn't work for me.

Declared two canonical fields in CanonicalParty and read it in the target XML file for the B2BUnit, but I'm getting blank.

<transformationExpression> relationshipType.contains('RE') ? businessCustomerNumber : '' </transformationExpression>

Created custom Canonical item type for these segments and tried to read it in the target but still same issue.

How to achieve this?

I want to store the KUNN2 value when PARVW = RE, so how to filter this? any handler?

Any way to debug and check the values of what store in Canonical type in DB for CCV2, as we don't have DB access there?


Thanks in advance.
Edit:
CanonicalPartyRelationshipSales:
<item>
            <type>CanonicalPartyRelationshipSales</type>
            <description>Canonical representation of a relationship between two parties</description>
            <attributes>
                <attribute>
                    <name>partyId</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression spel="true">{'WE','RE'}.contains(#root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARVW')) ? #root.getField('E1KNA1M-KUNNR') + '_KNA1' : null</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>relatedPartyId</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression spel="true">( '003'.equals(#root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-MSGFN')) ? #root.getField('E1KNA1M-KUNNR') : #root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-KUNN2') ) + '_KNA1'</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>relationshipType</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression>E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARVW</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>salesKey</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression spel="true">#root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-VKORG')+'_'+#root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-VTWEG')+'_'+#root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-SPART')</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>relationshipCounter</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression>E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARZA</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>messageFunction</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression>E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-MSGFN</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>relationshipTypeCP</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression>E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARVW</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <name>businessCustomerNumber</name>
                    <transformations>
                        <transformation>
                            <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                            <expression>E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-KUNN2</expression>
                        </transformation>
                    </transformations>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </item>

Target:
<item>
                    <type>CanonicalPartyReB2BUnit</type>
                    <exportCode>B2BUnit</exportCode>
                    <description>Update payerId</description>
                    <canonicalItemSource>CanonicalPartyRelationshipSales</canonicalItemSource>
                    <updatable>true</updatable>
                    <attributes>
                        <attribute>
                            <name>uid</name>
                            <transformationExpression>resolve('CanonicalParty').externalPartyId.concat('_').concat(salesKey)</transformationExpression>
                            <exportCode>uid[unique=true]</exportCode>
                            <mandatoryInHeader>true</mandatoryInHeader>
                        </attribute>
                        <attribute>
                            <name>payerId</name>
                            <transformationExpression>businessCustomerNumber</transformationExpression>
                            <exportCode>payerId</exportCode>
                        </attribute>
                    </attributes>
                </item> 

Already tried filtering this target with below, but it make the field blank when it checks for WE value.
<transformationExpression>
                relationshipType.contains('RE')?businessCustomerNumber:''
</transformationExpression>

So I tried below with handler
<transformationExpression>businessCustomerNumber</transformationExpression>

Spring.xml
<bean id="canonicalPartyRePublicationHandler" class="com.datahub.publication.CanonicalPartyRePublicationHandler">
        <property name="order" value="18" />
    </bean>

JAVA class
public class CanonicalPartyRePublicationHandler extends ConfigurablePublicationGroupingHandler {
   public <T extends com.hybris.datahub.model.CanonicalItem> List<T> group(T item, TargetItemCreationContext context) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  public <T extends com.hybris.datahub.model.CanonicalItem> boolean isApplicable(T item, TargetItemCreationContext context) {

        return "CanonicalPartyReB2BUnit".equals(context.getTargetItemTypeCode()) &&
              "RE".equals(item.getField("relationshipTypeCP"));
  }
}

Still its not working. Currently partyId updates with whichever is last segment (RE or WE) in Idoc. If I keep RE last it update with correct partyId.

You can use spel language to filter it like below:
<canonicalItems>
<item>
    <type>CanonicalParty</type>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <name>payerID</name>
            <transformations>
                <transformation>
                    <rawSource>RawDEBMAS</rawSource>
                    <expression spel="true">
                        <![CDATA[{'RE'}.contains(#root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARVW ')) ? #root.getField('E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-KUNN2') : null]]>
                    </expression>
                </transformation>
            </transformations>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</item>

You can use local development env for testing.

thanks @mkysoft, but this may null the payerID when its not RE. How to avoid this? we only want to update the payerID if there is RE otherwise keep it as is.

where to add above condition in raw? or target?

it must be raw. I am not sure about your data structure. You can check your CanonicalParty defination in xmls.

Its OOTB CanonicalPartyRelationshipSales structure, which has condition for both WE & RE, since there are use cases of both in address target we don't want to filter this at raw level, rather we want to set partyID (a custom attribute) in the B2BUnit from E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-KUNN2 from CanonicalPartyRelationshipSales when E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARVW is RE

so we can't filter this at Raw level, rather we want to set this during target B2BUnit update. I have just added a structure in the question.

added a update in the question.

If your TargetItem only updates the desired field on the B2BUnit, you can achieve your goal by using <filterExpression> attribute on your TargetItem. Your updated TargetItem definition should be as follows:
<item>
    <type>CanonicalPartyReB2BUnit</type>
    <exportCode>B2BUnit</exportCode>
    <description>Update payerId</description>
    <canonicalItemSource>CanonicalPartyRelationshipSales</canonicalItemSource>
    <updatable>true</updatable>
    <filterExpression>'RE'.equals(relationshipTypeCP)</filterExpression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <name>uid</name>
            <transformationExpression>resolve('CanonicalParty').externalPartyId.concat('_').concat(salesKey)</transformationExpression>
            <exportCode>uid[unique=true]</exportCode>
            <mandatoryInHeader>true</mandatoryInHeader>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>payerId</name>
            <transformationExpression>businessCustomerNumber</transformationExpression>
            <exportCode>payerId</exportCode>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</item> 

The part <filterExpression>'RE'.equals(relationshipTypeCP)</filterExpression> ensures that this item is published only when the condition is met.
For more details, refer to the following SAP documentation:
Filtering Canonical Items with SpEL Before Publication
